# Loading of PNG image through CGI program failing with errors

Tags: apache, bash, html, cgi

I am writing to write a cgi script to display a png image in a browser. When user clicks on the 'Submit' form in the HTML page , the CGI program is called to display the image .

But this is not working for me . The script is trying to open the PNG image in a browser,but the image contains the following error message

```
"The image “http://localhost/cgi-bin/image.sh?subbtn=Submit” cannot be  displayed, because it contains errors."
```

The following is the snippet of CGI code.

```
!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo "Content-type: image/png"

echo ""

echo  "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "Hi"

echo "<img src="/home/zaman/ssdggraph/SSDGhistory.png" alt="DG-Reports">"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

If I remove the below line from the above code , then the text `"DG-Reports"` in `alt` section from `img src` tag is displayed.

```
echo "Content-type: image/png"
```

Also if I write the same code in plain HTML page , the PNG image is displayed fine.

Please suggest what I am missing in the code to display the image without any errors ?

Comment: This seems to be a programming question, suggest move to SO.

Comment: relative path, your webserver can't access the file

Comment: @ChrisDown I disagrea this a a webserver problem

Comment: There is nothing in here that indicates this is anything other than a programming error.

Comment: Copied the image to DocumentRoot of webserver , but still the image cannot be loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify a URL for the `<IMG>`'s `src` attribute that can be reached from the browser.

`/home/zaman/ssdggraph/SSDGhistory.png` is unlikely to to satisfy that requirement. (You should probably have someting like `http://path_known_to_webserver/SSDGhistory.png`).

You should probably also read up on the concepts of web pages and cgi scripts. I would call a CGI "that displays an image", some program that would be referenced in the above URL and dynamically streams out the image data once the web pages refers to it and a browser asks for it. That might be what you mean, but it is kind of unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use content type, then blank line:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: image/png"
echo
cat /var/www/img/your-image.png
```